# gSOAP soapcpp2 #import: Cannot open file “soap12.h” for reading

Tags: c++, soap, gsoap

I'm in the process of moving from `gSOAP` 2.7 to 2.8.

soapcpp2 is returning the error `"#import: Cannot open file “soap12.h” for reading."`

I've found a similar post called "#import: Cannot open file “soap12.h” for reading gSoap in VS 2010" but my situation does not seem to be the same. In that case the application was including the .h file generated by `wsdl2h` and causing an error that caused the developer to change his `wsdl2h` options and that caused the error. The solution was to not include that .h file

This is what I did that worked in `gSOAP 2.7`

```
wsdl2h -s -t TypeMap.dat -o SOAP.h <multiple WSDL file names>

soapcpp2 -C SOAP.h
```

The wsdl2h execution gives some warnings that are new to 2.8. They are about multiple bindings being found and being collected as one service. I don't think they are important here

What is this `SOAP12.h` file it thinks it needs to import. `TypeMap.dat` does not contain an import like that

Answer (score 2):

The answer is this. gSOAP 2.8 requires the specification of a path to the import library in the gSOAP files in the execution of soapcpp2

This is done with the -I option

Comment: Agreed. To clarify: use `soapcpp2 -I <gsoap-home>/gsoap-2.8/gsoap/import` where `gsoap-2.8/gsoap/import` is a path in the gsoap distro, so specify the `<gsoap-home>` path.